# Can't access to a spinner in Java

Tags: java, android, spinner

I've got an activity where there is a button which opens an AlertDialog.
My dialog works and I decided to add a layout to it which contains a spinner.
So I have 3 documents :

- mainActivity.java : Its role is to open a Dialog
- activity_main.xml
- dialog_main.xml : The dialog's layout containing the spinner

I try to retrieve in mainActivity.java the spinner declared in dialog_main.xml (in order to add it an adapter) :

```
Spinner mySpinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.mySpinner);
```

However mySpinner = NULL, I can't find mySpinner. What is the problem ?

Comment: Post your activity layout file and where you use it. I.e. `setContentView`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
findViewById
```

as a method of the Activity class finds Views in your Activity's layout. When you are showing a Dialog, it is not part of your layout, so you have to `findViewById` in the Dialog's layout.

You are probably inflating a View for the Dialog that you show, you cou can use this view to find your Spinnner.

It probably looks like

```
View view = layoutInflater.inflate (...);
```

then you do

```
view.findViewById(...);
```

Post the code of how how show the Dialog and I'll show you if you can't do it.